# Size of the smallest subgroup of U(54) containing 7 and 19

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This is a purely computational question. Determine the size of the smallest subgroup of U(54) containing 7 and 19.

As for how things are defined,

$U(n) = \{k \in Z_n | gcd\{k,n\} = 1\}$, with multiplication mod n. That is, the set of $k \in Z_n$ such that $k$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

H is a **subgroup** of the group (G, $\cdot$), if
**1.** H is a subset of G,
**2.** and H with the same operation $\cdot$ as G is itself a group (satisfies closure, identity and inverses)

Now this seems like an easy enough question, but the answer I arrive, 8 is apparently wrong.

I've computed ahead of time U(54) = [1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53]]. And I found U(24) = [1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23] with size 8 and containing 7 and 19, but my answer is wrong. Got no clue where I'm going wrong with this seemingly simple enough question, would love some help.

Comment: Your mistake is thinking that $U(24)$ is part of $U(54)$. Some of the elements happen to have the same name as you've written them, but look at what $5 \times 5$ is in each one.

Comment: Oh, I see. Pretty silly mistake.

Comment: On that note though, is there an easier way to compute this or is it the tireless go through each one and check?

Comment: Hint: $7^3 = 19$ mod $54$.

Comment: From that hint, I take it the smallest size is actually 9. I'm pretty weak when it comes to modular arithmetic (will need to practice) but is the correct way computing the size of every subgroup in U(54), <1>, <5>, <7> and so on... up to <53> and determining which is the smallest or is there a smarter way to accomplish this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Just keep on calculating products like $7^m19^n\in U(54)$. Try for different choices of $m$ and $n$ until you get no new elements. The list you get is the subgroup generated by $7$ and $19$. Because this is an abelian group it is a good idea to try with $n=0$ first (and also $m=0$). Actually, from David Wheeler's hint $7^m19^n=7^{m+3n}$, so you only need to look for new powers of $7$. When you get back to $1=7^\ell$ for some $\ell>0$ you can stop, because from that point on the powers start repeating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using David's hint you need only examine the powers of $n$ where $7^n \mod 54\leq 54$. See the following for the solution.

> You don't need to be exhaustive as you can quickly recognize that $7^2=49,$ and so $7^3=343,$ taking this mod 54 provides an answer of 19. So you know that the subgroup is generated by $\{7,7^3\},$ is simply the subgroup generated $7.$ You can then compute the various powers of $7,$ noting that when taking powers which are multiples of 3, you can just look at powers of $19$ mod $54.$ Thus, you get
>   $$\langle 7\rangle =\{7,
> 49,
> 19,
> 25,
> 13,
> 37,
> 43,
> 31,
> 1
> \}
> $$in order of successive powers.

Comment: Bonus: If you're doing these types of things by hand, you can use https://sagecell.sagemath.org and a little python to compute a list of powers of 7 mod 54 and check your work. This way you can stay sane, and be lazy in the future. It's also great for hypothesis testing.

Comment: Can you over this again. I don't quite understand how this works. I do understand the brute force way, using <1>, <5>, etc. But that seems very time consuming

Comment: @Chubbles, do you mean you're computing $\langle 1\rangle,$ and $\langle 5\rangle$ as subgroups, for every element of $U(54)$? I don't quite understand what you're asking.